# How to fully erase promotional USB stick Autorun partition

Tags: usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, secure-erase

I have a 2GB USB stick from a free promotional giveaway.  It has a second "partition" with Autorun for advertising every time I insert it in a computer.  I know I can disable autorun, but how can I completely erase the disk?  Disk Utility on OS X thinks it's two separate disks, see partial output below.  I already tried `dd`.

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:        CD_partition_scheme                        *2.7 MB     disk1
   1:              CD_ROM_Mode_1 Autorun                 233.5 KB   disk1s0
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *2.1 GB     disk2
   1:               Windows_NTFS Untitled                2.1 GB     disk2s1

$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk1
dd: /dev/disk1: Permission denied
```

Comment: Promotional USB sitcks can have an area or the whole locked out by read only via the firmware. Pre-loaded and locked ones can cost more.  For $50 or less  you could have 10 promo 4gig flash drives with your own name/logo printed on them. why do you want to bother with these? do you have a whole box of them?

Comment: I wonder if its a U3 drive. There used to be tools floating around that could remove these.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a Windows operating system for this operation because the tools to make these changes are made for Windows. See my write-up at the link below for what it takes to place one of those partitions on a drive. The same processes to access and make a partition allows you to remove your partition. There will be a program specifically for the drive you are using. First, you'll need to use another program called ChipGenius and follow a few steps to determine what the exact model of the drive is you have and then what tool to use to modify it.

[How do I make a USB partition so no one can erase it](https://superuser.com/questions/1266067/how-do-i-make-a-usb-partition-so-no-one-can-erase-it?noredirect=1#comment1864504_1266067)